# The plugin generated 242 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages

Tags: wordpress

I'm a beginner in plugin development. I have created one plugin for the book. but it generates one error at an installation time_

> The plugin generated 242 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages

I searched for this type of error and the reason is ending PHP tag with space and etc but I don't think this type of issue here 
this is my code for the create table and add menu

```
<?php /*
* @package test plugin
*/
/*
 * Plugin Name: test
 * Description: This plugin is book plugin.
 * Plugin URI:
 * Author:
 * Author URI: 
 * Version: 1.0.0
*/
global $jal_db_version;
$jal_db_version = '1.0';
function jal_install() {
global $wpdb;
global $jal_db_version;
    $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'question';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE test3 (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        category varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
        question LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        qp1 LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        qp2 LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        qp3 LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        qp4 LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        qp5 LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        image varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
        option1 varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
        option2 varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
        option3 varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
        option4 varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
        dd1option1 varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
        dd1option2 varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
        dd1option3 varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
        dd1option4 varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
        answer LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
    update_option( 'jal_db_version', $jal_db_version );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'jal_install1' );
//adding in menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'at_try_menu');
    function enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bookstyle', plugins_url('/assets/style/style.css', __FILE__ ) );
}
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue');
    function at_try_menu() {
    //adding plugin in menu
    add_menu_page('book_menu', //page title
    'Book',//menu title
    'manage_options',//capabilities
    'Book_Menu',//menu slug
    'book_menu'//function
);
    //adding submenu to a menu
    add_submenu_page('Book_Menu',//parent page slug
    'Book Question',//page title
    'Question',//menu titel
    'manage_options',//manage optios
    'Book_Question',//slug
    'book_question'//function
);
    add_submenu_page( 'Book_Menu',//parent page slug
    'book_question',//$page_title
    'Result',// $menu_title
    'manage_options',// $capability
    'Book_Result',// $menu_slug,
    'book_result'// $function
);
}
//returns the root directory path of particular plugin
define('ROOTDIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is that you have a typo in the following line:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'jal_install1' );
```

You have an extra `1` in the function name. Removing that character, removes the error.

Also, something that might help in the future. The errors shown on the UI side of a Wordpress website is generally put there for users and not developers. But the system does log errors if error logging is enabled. You can do this by doing the following:

1. Change the second param in the line `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );` in the wp-config.php to `true` and that should trigger "debug" mode in your WP installation.
2. Second, add one of the following below the WP_DEBUG line to trigger the logging of errors to a file.

```
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
    -or-
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/tmp/wp-errors.log' );
```

3. if you want, you can even get the errors to show up on the screen by adding `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY',true)` to the wp-config.php file to see errors in HTML.

You can read more about this [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Hope this helps you.